# Existe alguma maneira de ativar a tela cheia do navegador com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Noto que os principais browsers ficam em modo tela cheia ao apertar a tecla F11, isso é uma funcionalidade do próprio browser ou é possível ativar isso através de algum código de JavaScript?

Caso não dê para fazer via código, como abrir uma nova janela somente com a página. Sem botões do navegador, e com a barra de endereços bloqueada etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Existe uma forma de ***simular*** o uso da ***tecla F11***, mas não pode ser automatizado.

Como se trata de uma funcionalidade que só o utilizador pode controlar, o mesmo terá que clicar num botão (*por exemplo*), de forma a activar o modo de ecrã inteiro.

- ## [Exemplo Alternar](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76169930/br.stackoverflow/demos/JavaScript/ecraInteiro_1.html)

  Este exemplo permite fazer a alternância entre ecrã inteiro e janela normal do navegador através do clique no mesmo elemento.

  **Botão de acção**

  ```html
  <input type="button" value="clique para alternar" onclick="toggleFullScreen()">
  ```

  **Função**

  ```js
  function toggleFullScreen() {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||    
     (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
      if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {  
        document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();  
      } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {  
        document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();  
      } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {  
        document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);  
      }  
    } else {  
      if (document.cancelFullScreen) {  
        document.cancelFullScreen();  
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {  
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();  
      } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {  
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();  
      }  
    }  
  }
  ```
- ## [Exemplo Mudar para Ecrã Inteiro](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76169930/br.stackoverflow/demos/JavaScript/ecraInteiro_2.html)

  Este exemplo permite activar o modo de ecrã inteiro sem fazer alternância, ou seja, o utilizador muda para ecrã inteiro mas para voltar ao ecrã normal terá que usar a tecla *F11*:

  **Botão de acção**

  ```html
  <input type="button" value="clique para ativar tela cheia" onclick="requestFullScreen()">
  ```

  **Função**

  ```js
  function requestFullScreen() {

    var el = document.body;

    // Supports most browsers and their versions.
    var requestMethod = el.requestFullScreen || el.webkitRequestFullScreen 
    || el.mozRequestFullScreen || el.msRequestFullScreen;

    if (requestMethod) {

      // Native full screen.
      requestMethod.call(el);

    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") {

      // Older IE.
      var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

      if (wscript !== null) {
        wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
      }
    }
  }
  ```

---

### Fontes e informação útil que encontrei sobre este assunto:

- [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>
- [Como fazer em JavaScript janelas em tela cheia (ocupar o ecrã inteiro)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1125084/352449) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>
- [Como fazer com que o navegador fique em tela cheia usando o evento da tecla F11 através de JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495373/how-to-make-browser-full-screen-using-f11-key-event-through-javascript) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>
- [Chrome Fullscreen API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836204/chrome-fullscreen-api) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>
- [jQuery fullscreen event plugin, version 0.2.0](https://github.com/ruidlopes/jquery-fullscreen) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>
- [jquery-fullscreen-plugin](https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

---

<sup>Créditos da resposta para o utilizador @Zuul [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10627148/352449) no StackOverflow original.</sup>

Comment: as urls estão todas quebradas do exemplo

Comment: Os links de exemplos já não funcionam mais.

Comment: @Bsalvo Obrigado, vou ver e colocar novamente online.

Comment: A quem deu voto negativo! Dá para explicar o que está errado na resposta ?

Answer (score 9):

É possível ativar tela cheia via JavaScript em [certos browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#BrowserCompatibility). Inclusive, é possível colocar um único elemento em fullscreen (como um vídeo), ou o documento inteiro.

Exemplo para o documento inteiro (extraído da [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode)):

```javascript
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
      !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

Essa API ainda não está totalmente standardizada. Um tempo atrás, havia uma restrição de que o modo tela cheia precisaria ser disparado por intervenção do usuário (como um clique em algo). Não tenho certeza se a restrição ainda existe, não vi referência no artigo atual da MDN (mas há [indícios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10352340/825789) de que essa limitação já existiu no Firefox).