# Tela cheia ao carregar a página

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

Como dar um Full Screen numa página assim que o browser terminar de carregá-la, mas que funcione também nos browsers do SO Android? Já usei o famoso `load` para disparar o evento após carregar a janela.

```
 $(window).load("on", function (){
     //...code...
 });
```

Mas, não obtive sucesso nem no Chrome do meu PC. A parte do Full Screen consegui resolver utilizando o plugin [fullscreen.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/). Contudo, não consigo fazer isso funcionar assim que a página termina de carregar. [Segue no Fiddle como tenho implementado até agora](http://jsfiddle.net/luitame/f7dg47kk/), disparando o *full screen* ao clicar sobre o texto que está numa tag `H1`. Também uso jQuery no projeto, mas o que está no Fiddle é só um teste. O projeto no qual vou usar isto é bem maior.

Comment: Tem certeza que não é `$(document).ready(function(){});` ou `$(function(){});`?

Comment: Já testei todos estes.

Comment: Que eu saiba fullscreen requer intervenção do usuário, o browser não permite que você dispare sem um clique ou algum outro tipo de interação.

Comment: @bfavaretto não tem como dá uma forçada nisto?

Comment: Se o browser deixasse você fazer isso, um site poderia encher sua tela de propaganda, por exemplo. Desagradável. Ver: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1855/existe-alguma-maneira-de-ativar-a-tela-cheia-do-navegador-com-javascript (duplicata?)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar iniciar utilizando a sintaxe abaixo:

```
$(window).on('load', function () { ... });
```

Eu também tentaria colocar um `setTimeout` como segurança. Depois que a página carregar, executa algo depois de 1 segundo. Exemplo:

```
$(window).load(function () {

   setTimeout(function () {
      telaCheia();
   }, 1000);

});

function telaCheia() {
  if (screenfull.enabled) {
    screenfull.request();
  }
  ...
}
```