# Entender um trecho de código javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá,  eu queria saber se alguem poderia me explicar essa  peca de código, ela ativa o modo Tela Cheia dos navegadores, porém eu queria entender e também queria saber se o "document.fullscreenElement" é algo nativo ou algo criado pela pessoa que fez.

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement
        && !document.webkitFullscreenElement
        && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement
                .webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    } else {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1855/existe-alguma-maneira-de-ativar-a-tela-cheia-do-navegador-com-javascript

Answer (score 2):

### As propriedades com e sem prefixos

- O `document.fullscreenElement`, `requestFullscreen` e `document.exitFullscreen` são nativos, mas só navegadores mais recentes o suportam
- O `document.mozFullScreenElement`, `mozRequestFullScreen` e `document.exitFullscreen` são nativos em navegadores mais antigos com tecnologia Mozilla, como navegadores Firefox desatualizados (provavelmente ainda é suportado para manter retrocompatibilidade), o `moz` é um prefixo usado para funcionalidades experimentais em navegadors Mozilla ou funcionalidades que só existem nestes navegadores, o CSS em Mozillas também usa o `-moz`, como prefixo
- O `document.webkitFullscreenElement`, `webkitRequestFullscreen` e `document.mozCancelFullScreen` são nativos em navegadores Chrome e Safari desatualizados (provavelmente ainda é suportado para manter retrocompatibilidade), o `webkit` é um prefixo usado para funcionalidades experimentais em navegadores Webkit ou funcionalidades que só existem nestes navegadores, o CSS em *Blink* e *Webkit* também usa o `-webkit`, como prefixo
- O `document.msFullscreenElement`, `msRequestFullscreen` e `document.msExitFullscreen` são usados pelo **somente** navegador IE11

### O uso de `document.fullscreenElement`

A propriedades `document.fullscreenElement`, `document.mozFullScreenElement`, `document.webkitFullscreenElement` e `document.msFullscreenElement`, retornam o elemento que estiver em fullscreen, se não tiver nada em fullscreen irá retornar `null`, no caso do seu código estão sendo usados para checar se não tem nada em fullscreen para assim executar o código, acaso esteja ele irá executar o `document.exitFullscreen` (ou com prefixos)

---

### O Motivo de usar os prefixos moz, ms, webkit

Hoje praticamente todos navegadores usam somente `document.fullscreenElement`, o código que você está usando é o que chamamos de **retrocompatibilidade** ou **compatibilidade reversa**, é um termo muito usado em console de jogos, mas é totalmente válido para quase qualquer coisa, o objetivo da retro-compatibilidade é suportar tecnologias mais antigas, acaso o usuário tenha um navegador mais antigo, ou computador que não suporta navegadores mais novos.