# scrollTop em FullScrenn jQuery

Tags: jquery

Na tela em modo normal uso no clique de um botão o direcionamento da tela para uma div no topo:

`$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.backTop').offset().top}, 150);`

Mas, tendo a tela em Full Screen como fazer esta função funcionar?

https://jsfiddle.net/f6xr93b7/

Comment: Tem uma resposta aqui dá uma olhada nela: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1855/existe-alguma-maneira-de-ativar-a-tela-cheia-do-navegador-com-javascript

Comment: Boa chefe, mas, meu fullscreen já está funcionando, meu problema é enviar o usuario para uma div no topo da página quando esta tela estiver em fullscreen

Comment: Mas qual seria a dificuldade então sNniffer?

Comment: Isso aqui não funciona `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.backTop').offset().top}, 150);` em fullscreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido,

Simplesmente ao usar:

`$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.backTop').offset().top}, 150);`

estava atribuindo ao scroll do body, mas, deveria estar atribuindo ao scroll do div que está em fullscreen, ficando:

```
$('#leitor').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".backTop").offset().top
}, 150);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver seu problema basta substituir o código:
`$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('.backTop').offset().top}, 150);`

por este `$('#leitor').animate({scrollTop:$('.leitor_top').offset().top}, 150);`

Pois quem fica em tela cheia é a div chamada "leitor".
Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Teste isso:

```
var suaDiv = document.getElementById("leitor");
        suaDiv.scrollTop = 0;
```

Comment: joia? Testado e sem sucesso ainda